# VBA Error: Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter

Tags: excel, vba, class, let

I have a very simple Class definition.
Class Sheetwriter is defined as follows:

```
Option Explicit

'Works off of the ActiveCell
'Helps you write data into the cells


Private pCornerCell As String


Public Property Get CornerCell()

    CornerCell = pCornerCell

End Property


Public Property Let CornerCell(Value As String)

    pCornerCell = Value

    Range(Value).Select

End Property
```

I get a compile error that I don't understand.
Definitions of property procedures for the same property are inconsistent, or the property procedure has an optional parameter.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Public Property Get CornerCell()
```

That's returning an implicit `Variant`, since no return type was specified.

```
Public Property Get CornerCell() As String
```

That's returning the `String` that the compiler is seeing in the `Property Let` member, and fixes your problem.

FWIW, that `Range(Value).Select` statement doesn't belong in there at all, and you don't *want* to work off the active cell and sprinkle `Select` and `Activate` statements everywhere.

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513) for some tips about avoiding that.